# how to hide original downloading link of external site using php

Tags: php

so I need your solution.
my site, example.com/test.php when user click on it, it will download file from external site externalsite.com/file.mkv

I just want to mask the external site url, so that when user click on example.com/test.php it will get file from external site url and never show original site url.

I have try below code but not working

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

$filename = "https://externalsite.com/20230113100300if_/https%3A%2F%2Fs38.123apps.com%2Fvconv%2Fd%2F63c12a662da0e_mkv_ymfVHPvq.mkv";

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.""); 

header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');

readfile($filename); 

?>
```

Comment: it would require your php script to download the resource and to serve it to your client. Are you sure of what you are asking?

Comment: @DiegoD That's what it does with `readfile($filename)`

Comment: Why doesn't the script use `$id`?

Comment: I was genuinely concerned ... I read mkv... if I'm not missing something it will strongly affect your traffic usage

Comment: Oh it'll definitely create traffic.  Even if the file is properly streamed and never stored on the server or in too much of a memory footprint, the entire file is still transferring both to and from the server.  So for a 100MB file this will generate 200MB of traffic for the server every time.  That's essentially the price for the requirement of the client not knowing the source of the file.

Comment: @David give me a working code

Comment: @ZamaniVogue: Demanding much?  Perhaps you could benefit to learn more about this community and how we can help you... Please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 2):

Change the name in the `Content-disposition:` header to just the basename, not the full URL.

So replace

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename."");
```

with

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filename));
```

Comment: can you please write your own code and make me to understand

Comment: What don't you understand? Just replace your header line with this one.

Comment: it downloading just the name

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? You didn't want them to see the whole URL that it came from.